# No, I wouldn't - what does it mean

Tags: grammar

You ask a person to sit on a chair: Please go sit on the chair.

And this person responds: No, I wouldn't.

What does the meaning of this response? Does he mean that he isn't quite decided and he himself is not sure what he would do?

Comment: That response to the imperative is nonsensical in English. It is meaningless. It _would_ be meaningful in response to _"Would you like to go sit on the chair?"_ In the alternative, a meaningful response to the provided imperative might be: _"No, I would rather not."_ This means that the person does not want to comply with the imperative.

Comment: It could make sense if the sentence elided some words: "No, I wouldn't ***do that***."

Comment: @Robusto Yes! And the sentence _"Yes, I would"_ would mean _"No, I wouldn't"_ if the words _"not do that"_ were elided. This elision deal is fun!